# append text onto already existing sqlite entry

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there a way to append text onto text already in the my sqlite database without manually typing the old code again?

I image it would be something like this:

```
UPDATE myTable set myText = myText || 'new text'
```

But when I try it in android it returns an "Empty bindArgs" error

Method:

```
public void appendConvo(String name, String convo) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("update friends set convo = convo || '" + convo + "' where name = '" + name + "'" , null);
    db.close();
}
```

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.acbk.acbk, PID: 13438
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
      at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4745)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22546)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4740)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702) 
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22546) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty bindArgs
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1791)
      at com.acbk.acbk.DataBaser.appendConvo(DataBaser.java:81)
      at com.acbk.acbk.Chat.send(Chat.java:137)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4740) 
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702) 
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22546) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `execSQL(String, Object[])` on which the Official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)) says:

> **void execSQL (String sql, Object[] bindArgs)**
>   Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE

Use `execSQL` instead:

```
public void appendConvo(String name, String convo) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("update friends set convo = convo || '" + convo + "' where name = '" + name + "'");
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL strings are delimited with quotes; if your string contains quotes, you have to properly escape them.

To avoid formatting problems like this, use parameters instead:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE friends SET convo = convo || ? WHERE name = ?",
           new Object[]{ convo, name });
```